# crypto-js AES exchange with Marketing Cloud (AMPScript)

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to use crypto-js to manage encryption and decryption of data from Marketing Cloud (AMPScript).
I checked the lib docs and several "guides" on the web. The lib docs don't talk about using the IV, while other guides are very confusing.
I initially tried to work with a simple flow of encrypt-decrypt, but I could't seem to get it right. The decrypted value was always empty.

Now thanks to Topaco, I changed the key to be 12 characters long and now I can encrypt/decrypt.

I also had to adjust the decrypt part a bit, passing a cypher object.

> I'll need to check with them how exactly they're using the parameters and if they're doing multiple encryptions in order to work with their sample data. I'll update the question.

Here is my code.

```js
const key = enc.Utf8.parse('Harold%Finch');
const iv = enc.Utf8.parse('11111111111111111111111111111111');
const secret = enc.Utf8.parse('secret@email.com');
const encrypted = AES.encrypt(secret, key, {
  iv: iv,
  mode: mode.CBC,
  padding: pad.Pkcs7,
});

const encryptedString = encrypted.toString();
// "2VxmNeqlTolVpgHrk+tdEO3+xS8XOjClikUjB+zAGis="

// Convert the base64-encoded string to a CipherParams object
const ciphertext = enc.Base64.parse(encryptedString);
const cipherParams = lib.CipherParams.create({ ciphertext });

const decrypted = AES.decrypt(cipherParams, key, {
  iv: iv,
  mode: mode.CBC,
  padding: pad.Pkcs7,
});

// Convert the decrypted data to a string (UTF-8)
const decryptedString = decrypted.toString(enc.Utf8);

console.info('decrypted', decryptedString);
// "secret@email.com"
```

On their end the code looks like:

```
set @encAES = EncryptSymmetric(@str, "aes", @null, @password, @null, @salt, @null, @initVector)
```

But I'm still not getting the same result.
I'm checking this documentation to understand how it works precisely in terms of defaults (the padding for example)

https://ampscript.guide/encryptsymmetric/

Blitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bc5qhc)

Comment: The key sizes allowed for AES are 16, 24 and 32 bytes, the IV size allowed for AES is 16 bytes. Your code violates both.

Comment: Ok thanks, I actually got that error during some tests on one of those websites...
Let me try correcting those...then I'll point out to the Salesforce guy that the bytes sequence can't be correct...
While the real key, if encoded in base64 would be 16 characters long...

Comment: It is possible that a key derivation function is applied. Without knowing the Salesforce code/logic and/or documentation, it is hard to find a CryptoJS implementation that would allow a Salesforce compatible encryption/decryption. Non-productive sample data would also be useful.

Comment: Ok thanks again, at least now I can encrypt and decrypt...tomorrow I'll check with the Salesforce guy how exactly they encode on their side...
The idea is to decrypt a sample string he gave me but of course right now it doesn't work!

Comment: *...I changed the key to be 12 characters long...*: Note that 12 bytes is also an invalid AES key size (as stated: 16, 24 and 32 bytes are valid). CryptoJS does allow encryption with such an invalid key (due to a bug), but the result is not AES compliant and therefore cannot be decrypted with any AES library (except CryptoJS itself, and that only if the key size is a multiple of 4 bytes). Also the 8 bytes IV is invalid. CryptoJS fixes this *implicitly* by padding to 16 bytes with 0x00 values.

Comment: If you want to use a passphrase like *Harold%Finch*, the correct way is to apply a reliable key derivation function (so at least PBKDF2). CryptoJS has a built in key derivation (which is used when the key is passed as string), namely `EVP_BytesToKey()`, but this KDF is nowadays considered insecure and therefore should not be applied.

Comment: Hi @Topaco I confirm that I was able to do everything...They were using DES, not AES. I had them change their code. On my side I needed exactly to create the encryption key using PBKDF2.
I'll post the code in a few hours.
Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it appears that under the hood the `EncryptSymmetric` method in **AMPScript** creates a key from the `password` and `salt`, using the `PBKDF2` key derivation (as stated by @Topaco).

So we need to do the same.
I'm using `crypto-js` because I have a set of encode-decode functions shared between frontend and edge middleware, but if you're at backend side you can use the **native** `crypto` implementation of *Node*.

The original AMPScript code:

```
  %%[ 
    set @str = [EmailAddress]
    set @password="xyQ8n55tKi$@@4dy"
    set @initVector='198e3f0733ec4791'
    set @salt = "c2dc41eeab1e513a"  

    set @encAES = EncryptSymmetric(@str, "aes", @null, @password, @null, @salt, @null, @initVector)
    set @decAES = DecryptSymmetric(@encAES, "aes", @null, @password, @null, @salt, @null, @initVector)
  ]%%
```

```js
  import { PBKDF2, AES, enc, mode, pad, algo } from 'crypto-js';

  const str = 'some@email.com';
  const password = 'xyQ8n55tKi$@@4dy';
  const initVector = '198e3f0733ec4791';
  const salt = 'c2dc41eeab1e513a';

  // Encrypting the string using AES
  const encAES = encryptAES(str, password, salt, initVector);
  console.info('ENC AES', encAES);

  // Decrypting the encrypted string using AES
  const decAES = decryptAES(encAES, password, salt, initVector);
  console.info('DEC AES', decAES);

  function buildKey(password, salt) {
    return PBKDF2(password, enc.Hex.parse(salt), {
      keySize: 256 / 32,
      iterations: 1000,
      hasher: algo.SHA1,
    });
  }

  function encryptAES(data, password, salt, initVector) {
    return AES.encrypt(data, buildKey(password, salt), {
      iv: enc.Hex.parse(initVector),
      mode: mode.CBC,
      padding: pad.Pkcs7,
    }).toString();;
  }

  function decryptAES(data, password, salt, initVector) {

    return AES.decrypt(data, buildKey(password, salt), {
      iv: enc.Hex.parse(initVector),
      mode: mode.CBC,
      padding: pad.Pkcs7,
    }).toString(enc.Utf8);
  }
```

> Very wierdly on their side they said they can't use a 16 byte IV and we stuck with the 32 byte. I will check this in the future.